# Find the smallest angle possible from the diagram

Tags: geometry, triangles

[image]

> On the diagram above, $AB=BC=CD=DE$. The measure of $\angle ADE$ is expressed in integer degrees. Find the smallest possible $\angle ADE$.

This is what I got so far:

Let $\angle BAC=a$.
So, $\angle CBD=2a$ and $\angle DCE=\angle DEC=3a$

Hence, $\angle ADE=180^\circ-a-3a=180^\circ-4a$

This was a bit iffy, but I thought that $0<\angle DCE<90^\circ$, so $0<a<30^\circ$.

From there I got $60^\circ<180^\circ-4a<180^\circ \Rightarrow 60^\circ<\angle ADE<180^\circ$. I got the smallest $\angle ADE$ as $\,61^\circ$ as a result, but it is wrong.

How do you solve this question?

Comment: Do you know what the correct answer is?

Comment: @CalvinLin Yes, it is $64˚$.

Comment: If so, my guess is that they wanted all of the angles to be integers (in particular $ \angle BAC$). This might be a phrasing issue? $\quad$ There is nothing wrong with your work, and I agree that 61 should be the correct answer for the statement of this problem.

Comment: @CalvinLin I see, thanks. I'll look out for other answers just in case, however.

Comment: (A) When we have BAC=30 , we will end up with the limiting Case where DEA=90 & ADE=60 , which is technically the minimum. (B) It might be that the Introductory level of the text book is not considering angles like BAC=29.9999 , hence it straight away goes to BAC=29. (C) Now , that makes BDC=58 with DEC=87. With CDE=6 , we get ADE=BDC+CDE=58+6=64 , where we have got what the text book wanted , even though 60 is the Correct Answer. (D) I agree with @CalvinLin that your work is Essentially Correct & the text book is wanting Integers.